Me obliga a colocar un try "Convert to try-with-resources" cada vez que utilizo java.util.Scanner;
Estoy empezando a programar con Java y esto me lleva pasando desde el principio , aunque el código esté bien y funcione correctamente , cada vez que hago un Scanner , aún habiéndolo cerrado al final , por terminal me sale "Convert to try with resources" , cosa que no sale a otras personas incluso con el mismo código copy/paste.
Puede ser por estar usando Java 17? Si alguien tiene idea de que puede ser se lo agradecería!
Dejo una captura para que se vea , el código da igual ya que me sale con cualquiera.

El error de The assigned value is never used no es por el Scanner entrada , es por un int num=0; , he tenido que poner directamente int num; para que no salga el error

No parece ser que te obligue, sino que te da una advertencia (probablemente estás usando Netbeans). Si no sabés qué es un try-with-resources, ¡revisá la documentación! Existe desde Java 7.

Estas respuestas están relacionadas.

Define "Me obliga". El icono de bombilla indica sugerencia, el triángulo amarillo es un warning (que tampoco obliga a nada!) y cuando te "obliga" es porque algo has roto. Ningún IDE te obliga a nada, eres libre de escribir lo que quieras y hacer lo que quieras. Otra cosa es que lo que hagas luego funcione o no :) En este caso te sugiere usar el try with resources (aunque técnicamente podrías usar un try "normal" con finally)  porque el Scanner se puede quedar abierto y usando el try-with-resources se cierra automáticamente, previniendo leakings. Simplemente son buenas prácticas.

Muchísimas gracias @Benito-B , así me queda clarísimo. No me obliga , pero no quedaba tranquilo viendo algo resaltado en amarillo jeje

Muchas gracias como siempre @padaleiana !! Solucionado :)

This question is similar to: Se deben cerrar los FileInputStream y FileOutputStream usados por clase Properties?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

El try-with-resource se utiliza para manejar excepciones y liberacion automaticamente de recursos al ejecutar el codigo dentro del try - catch.
Basicamente es una sugerencia que te hace el editor de codigo para manejar las excepciones al haber una entrada de datos abierta y a su vez cerrar los recursos del scanner para. (Si dejas el scanner abierto, eso consumirá más recursos de tu dispositivo, para cerrarlo manualmente es usando el nombre de instancia de tu objeto scanner y usar el metodo de la clase scanner .close();)
Lo de manejar las excepciones es para evitar que un programa se cuelgue (se caiga) por un error no esperado, en este caso tu programa sin un try - catch, al pedir un numero y el usuario ingrese otro caracter diferente a un numero, el programa automaticamente se detendrá y lanzará una excepcion.
